# Netezza - making UDF functions available to multiple DBs

Tags: function, lua, netezza

The LUA Developer's Guide ( part of Netezza Analytics 3.0 ) has instructions for "compiling" .nzl functions using the "nzlua" command.  Unfortunately, the function seems to be only available in the DB that is defined in the environmental variable NZ_DATABASE when the "nzlua" command is executed - see command output immediately below.

**Question:  How does one make the compiled function available to all databases on the appliance ?**  i.e. without altering the NZ_DATABASE env variable and redoing the nzlua command for each DB ( including user sandbox DBs ).

```
[nz@nzh1p01 examples]$ /nz/extensions/nz/nzlua/bin/nzl nzlua isdate.nzl
Compiling: isdate.nzl
####################################################################
UdxName      =  isdate
UdxType      =  UDF
Arguments    =  VARCHAR(40),VARCHAR(40)
Result       =  BOOL
Dependencies =  INZA.INZA.LIBNZLUA_3_0_0
NZUDXCOMPILE OPTIONS: (--nullcall --unfenced --mem 2m)
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Comment: I can't verify this as I don't have the documentation available atm, but I don't believe this is possible. Custom functions have to be installed for each database separately.

Answer (score 1):

The function should available in all the databases however you will need to call it using the full path. Database..function

Answer (score 1):

Add the database that you registered the function into to the "search_path" environment variable in the `/nz/data/postgresql.conf` file.  The function can then be reference d from anywhere :-)

Comment: This is the 'most accurate' answer in my opinion